# iOS: draw a UIImage of circle at a UIView's center

Tags: ios

I have a circle image with radius 50, and now I want to put the circyle's center the same as my View's center like this:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    UIImage *arrow = [UIImage imageWithPDFNamed:@"circle" atSize:CGSizeMake(50, 50)];
    [arrow drawAtPoint:self.center];
}
```

But drawAtPoint is not drawing at the center.
I want to know how to locate the center of the image? so I can draw it?

Comment: First. If the radius is 50 then the size should be 100, 100. Also, you should be drawing at the point that is 50 to the left and above the centre. Not at the centre. It uses the origin (top left point) and places it at the point you specified.

Comment: it is a PDF so it will scale to any size you make, without loosing quality.

Comment: Yeah but you said you wanted a radius of 50. Just wanted to check you weren't doing it at the wrong size. So draw at point should be at 25, 25 off the centre point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From Apple's documentation for UIImage

> This method draws the entire image in the current graphics context,
>   respecting the image’s orientation setting. In the default coordinate
>   system, images are situated down and to the right of the specified
>   point. This method respects any transforms applied to the current
>   graphics context, however.

So offset the center with half the image width and height to draw the center of the image on the center of your view.

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    CGSize imageSize = CGSizeMake(50,50);
    UIImage *arrow = [UIImage imageWithPDFNamed:@"circle" atSize:imageSize];
    [arrow drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(self.center.x-imageSize.width/2., self.center.y-imageSize.height/2.)];
}
```

Comment: Awesome, perfectly centered

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to draw it, just assign it's center to your view's center

```
arrowsuperview.center = self.center
```

Comment: Does UIImage has a center property? I think the answer is NO. Yours only works with UIImageView, plus your UIImage in UIImageView must have the center aligned. Otherwise your UIImage will still have an offset to the center

Comment: You're correct. should replace arrow's superview.center = self.center

Answer (score 0):

Try this. This is how you find the center of a subview inside a view

```
childView.center = CGPointMake(parentView.bounds.size.width / 2, parentView.bounds.size.height / 2);
```

Comment: I am not looking at a UIView, but a UIImage center

Comment: look at the code that I have provided and think for a minute how to use it

Answer (score 0):

try this..

```
    UIImageView *circleImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 50, 50)];
    circleImageView.image = yourCircleImage;
    circleImageView.center = self.view.center;
    [circleImageView setContentMode:UIViewContentModeCenter];
    [self.view addSubview:circleImageView];
```

Comment: Tried but not work... My UIImage has offset to the UIImageView. Pieter has a great answer

Answer (score 0):

Calculate the center of the UIView using following code and draw the image using the drawAtPoint function.

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect 
{
   CGPoint ptCenter = {rect.size.width / 2.0f, rect.size.height / 2.0f};
   [arrow drawAtPoint:ptCenter];
}
```

Another simple approach:

You can also achieve the result using storyboard/xib and Auto Layout. Instead of drawing the image in drawRect use an UIImageView to hold your image and position the imageview using Autolayout constraints.